# Add member method as a resource

Tags: wpf, resources

I'm implementing a class that contains an ObservableCollection and in my XAML I have a polyline. 
I successfully binded the XAML dataContext to the this class and the polyline to the Observable collection. But now, of course, I'm facing a wrong type conversion. 
I found an example of value converter and I added it to my code but I'm not able to add it as a resource in my XAML ...

The overall structure looks like that

```
public class externalClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<Point> debugCh1 { get; set; }

    public void test() 
    { 
         ... performo modifications
          on debugCh1 for testing purposes...
    }

    public class PointCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        .. implements convert and cnverBack
    }
}
```

For the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="tester.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="277" Width="525" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:binding;assembly=binding" xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:deviceManager;assembly=deviceManager" Closing="Window_Closing">


    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PointCollectionConverter x:Key="pointCollectionConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>


           ... The window Itself ...
        <Polyline Points="{Binding debugCh1}" />
           ...
</Window>
```

And for the C# behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 
    private externalClass toTest;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = toTest;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        toTest.test();
    }
}
```

The whole thing works nice but for the  `<local:PointCollectionConverter..`

Compiler says `The type 'local:PointCollectionConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.`

Any suggestions on how to add this reference??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to make sure the namespaces are lined up.  I'd start by separating your converter class from the `externalClass` class (I'm not sure it's even possible to reference nested-classes like that from XAML):

```
namespace MyCompany.MyProject
{
    public class PointCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        .. implements convert and cnverBack
    }
}
```

Now you can define the `local` xmlns and link it to `MyCompany.MyProject`:

```
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyCompany.MyProject"
```

And with that the converter should be accessible as written.

```
<local:PointCollectionConverter x:Key="pointCollectionConverter"/>
```

Comment: If you can reference nested classes i'd expect the syntax to be something like `<local:externalClass+PointCollectionConverter />` though that probably won't work.

Comment: I've not tested the nested reference but after struggling a bit with the namespaces now everything is together and working :)
Main problem was that in most of the examples they assume you declare xmlns:local .. and it is not automatically generated :(

Good to know it!  Thanks !